# 07 Mini Cooper Base model misfire

Tags: engine

I have a base mini 2007 and it misfires at start
 Throws coded p0300 p0303,p0304. I checked and theres spark at all the plugs. If i remove plugs 3&4 it runs with the misfire. When i remove either 1or 2 the engine stalls. Dont get it. I thought it maybe a coil pack but like i said tjeres spark at all the cylinders.  I removed each plug to check.  Any one have any ideas what it could be? HELP!

Comment: Have you tried swapping the coils from one cylinder to another, then retest?  Hae you tried swapping plugs, then retest?  Question: How many miles on the vehicle?  (Remember that one of the failures of spark plugs is sealing between ceramic and thread mount. Under compression the leak causes there to be no spark...)   test and report back?  Additionally, why are we chasing spark, not fuel (injectors)?

Comment: I did swap the coils around. If i remove the coil connection from the 4th and 3rd coil there is no change in the engine and it stays running with no change. If i remove the connection from the 1st and 2nd  coil the engine shuts off. Mind you i do it one at a time. I checked each plug for spark and all four sbowed spark. The sparkplug boot that incloses the plugs body did h as ve slices at the bottom going vertical about 1/2 a inch up. Did seem to effect its function.  Dosen't seem to have a vacuum leak either. Cant figure this out.

Comment: Er, wrong test. 1) Clear codes, swap coils on plug, read new codes. 2). Clear codes. Put coils back to original location, Swap spark plugs. 1—>3, 2–>4.  Read new codes. We’d like to know if the fault codes follow the coils or follow the spark plugs.  QUESTION AGAIN: HOW MANY MILES ON THE VEHICLE?

Comment: The mini has 108000 on it . When the codes where read it was at Autozone.  I have tried reading the coded with my OBD2 and for some reason it says no codes in memory.  But if i erase the codes stored codes it will reset and erase the check engine light. After a bit it will come back on . Again when i connect my scanner it says no codes

Comment: When i did swap the coils on plugs there was no difference in the engine behavior.  It still ran with a misfire.

Comment: 108K indicates it could be time to replace the platinum spark plugs.  The tests I indicate require a functional code reader.  I too, have an old reader that seems to miss stuff sometimes.  Knowing the specific error codes tells us which cylinders have the problem. Obviously if the defect moves with part swaps, that confirms which part needs replacing.  Perhaps its time [to spend $20 on new reader?](https://amzn.to/2VHdulz)   Note: I'm told the wifi version is a bit more practical, works for both iOS and Android.

Comment: But if the problem dosen't move when i switch the coils and it continues to misfire in the same cylinders what could that mean? Also if all the spark plugs are sparking wjen i remove them and crank the motor would that indicate goid coils and spark plugs?

Comment: What reader should i get and where from for that price? All the ones I've seen are 100+.

Comment: Use your mouse (computer) or finger (mobile phone) to click on the link i provided above.